# ExpressJS Router URL Matching

Tags: express

code below, when I visit url like this `http://localhost/`. It can match the first one, but when I visit `http://localhost/detail-999`, It match the first one again. It can not match the second one.

I want that when I visit `http://localhost` or `http://localhost/list-1-1` can match the first one and when visit `http://localhost/detail-999` can match the second one correctly...

I have no idea to fix this problem...

```
router.get('/|/list-:type-:page', function (req, res) {});
router.get('/detail-:itemId', function (req, res) {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to wrap it to brackets like this:

```
app.get('(/|/list-:type-:page)', function (req, res) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```express
router.get('/list/:type/:page', function (req, res, next) {});
router.get('/detail/:itemId', function (req, res, next) {});
```

It can be problematic designing your routes as you did. If you have params that can not be changed then you should handle the dashes in the route's action method and just do a `req.params.list_name.split('-')`